# What is the background of the number 1024?

Tags: memory, storage, history

I couldn't figure out where the number 1024 came from. Of course I found out that the number can be described as 2^10. I know that 1 byte = 8 bits. My question now is why did you take ^10? My assumption: 1024 is the next number in the binary system to thousand.Furthermore I found information about Kilo (=1000) and Kibi (=1024). But that didn't answer my question, because I didn't find a background to the +24? 1024 seems like a magic number.

I'm looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Because of how binary numbers work, powers of two are convenient for computers and programmers. 1024 is also convenient for humans because it's very close to the base-10 value of 10<sup>3</sup>.

You are right that exponents which are also powers of two would make more sense for computers in many contexts. But 256 and 65536 and other even powers of two are not as close to numbers we humans can quickly conceptualize and manipulate in our mind.

Answer (score 1):

Many different powers of 2 are heavily used in computing, not just 1024.  You'll find 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 4096, 1048576, 1073741824, and other multiples everywhere.

Computers are binary, so every number relating to computers, how they work, hardware, files, etc. are multiples of two.  If you want to work with color, sound, or pretty much anything on a computer, it needs to be translated to some binary form.

There are some basic building blocks, like bytes, so many of the computer-related numbers aren't just multiples of 2, they're multiples of multiples like 8.

Computer-related numbers cover a huge range of sizes, so certain multiples tend to be used as building blocks.  Think of the analogy of measuring distance and physical size.  We have units and multiples of units to give us numbers that are a reasonable scale for the different things we need to measure -- nanometers for microscopic stuff, millimeters and centimeters for small stuff, kilometers for longer distances, etc.  They're all multiples, and we use the particular multiple that's convenient for what we need to measure.  We don't measure the distance to the moon in nanometers.

Similarly, computer-related stuff is different sizes for different purposes, and we use convenient multiples as the units for what's needed.  A fairly common scale that's needed is a number in the ballpark of 1000.  Humans are used to working with powers of 10, so that works out well in terms of being easy for humans to relate to the number and to be able to do basic math.  The binary multiple that happens to come close is 1024.

Answer (score -1):

Binary memory units are bits. They can either be 1 or 0, so they have two states.
When combining two bits they can have state 00, 01, 10 or 11. Thus 2^2 states.

That's why memory capacities comes in powers of 2. 10 bits equal 2^10 different possible states, which is 1024 different states.

Now since, all memory addresses are being addressed in binary as well, it makes sense to not only build lets say 3 memory units; address 00, 01 and 10.
Instead it is more efficient to also use the fourth address 11 and thus building your hardware in powers of 2.

This is why this concept keeps on going for all memory-based units.

Comment: Alright, but why ^10? I thought everything in the binary system is witten in blocks of 4. For example: 1001 1001. Now, why are we using something like this: 10 1001 1001?

Comment: the 2^10 comes from it being very close as 10^3, so your intution about that was right..